# How to perform Dynamic Join using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have two collections. Each collection contains instances of a specific type. I need to join these two collections using one of the properties of the instances from each of the collections. The issue is that I will come to know which property to use for join only during run time. So how do I write the LINQ query for a dynamic Join? Here is the code with LINQ query with static join. In the following sample code you will notice that I am joining two collections using MyTran.MyAmountUSD = YourTran.YourAmountUSD. But in real scenario, I will come to know which property to use for join only during run time. So sometime I might be required to join on MyTran.MyAmountGBP = YourTran.YourAmountGBP.

```
class MyTran
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double MyAmountUSD { get; set; }
    public double MyAmountGBP { get; set; }
}

class YourTran
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double YourAmountUSD { get; set; }
    public double YourAmountGBP { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<MyTran> fMyTranList = new List<MyTran>();
        List<YourTran> fYourTranList = new List<YourTran>();

        fMyTranList.Add(new MyTran { Id = 1, MyAmountGBP = 100, MyAmountUSD = 1000 });
        fMyTranList.Add(new MyTran { Id = 2, MyAmountGBP = 101, MyAmountUSD = 2000 });

        fYourTranList.Add(new YourTran { Id = 11, YourAmountGBP=100, YourAmountUSD=1000 });
        fYourTranList.Add(new YourTran { Id = 12, YourAmountGBP = 102, YourAmountUSD = 3000 });

        var query = from fMyTrans in fMyTranList
                    join fYourTrans in fYourTranList
                         on fMyTrans.MyAmountUSD equals fYourTrans.YourAmountUSD
                    select new
                    {
                        MyId = fMyTrans.Id,
                        YourId = fYourTrans.Id,
                        MyAmtUSD = fMyTrans.MyAmountUSD,
                        MyAmtGBP = fMyTrans.MyAmountGBP,
                        YourAmtUSD = fYourTrans.YourAmountUSD,
                        YourAmtGBP = fYourTrans.YourAmountGBP
                    };

        foreach (var fMatch in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(fMatch);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: erm, set `query` to different values depending on a condition. `switch` or `if` statements should help.

Comment: Thanks Jodrell. Unfortunately "if" or "switch" statement is not an option. For simplicity I just mentioned two columns. However, in real case we have more than 50 different columns and user can choose to join on any of those columns. Also the name, number and data type of columns varies from our client to client but we need to write a generic code so that it can cater to all of them. That's the reason static query won't work in our case and we need to create the LINQ query dynamically.

Comment: I suggest you write a question that elaborates on this idea.

Comment: Is the result *really* an anonymous object? Or do you in actual fact have a concrete class for the result?

Comment: Thanks Jamiec. I am not sure at this stage. We are still in design phase and have not decided anything about concrete class or anonymous object. As the schema of data may vary from our client to client, we will be using some kind of dynamic class, such as ExpandoObject.

Answer (score 5):

The first clue to solving this is to re-write your join using [lamda syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.join%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) for the `Join`

```
var query = fMyTranList.Join(fYourTranList,
               a => a.MyAmountGBP, 
               b => b.YourAmountGBP, 
               (c,d) => new
                    {
                        MyId = c.Id,
                        YourId = d.Id,
                        MyAmtUSD = c.MyAmountUSD,
                        MyAmtGBP = c.MyAmountGBP,
                        YourAmtUSD = d.YourAmountUSD,
                        YourAmtGBP = d.YourAmountGBP
                    });
```

Live: http://rextester.com/OGC85986

Which should make it clear that making this dynamic would require passing in to your "generic" join function 3 functions

1. a `Func<MyTran,TKey>` function for selecting the key for LHS
2. a `Func<YourTran,TKey>` function for selecting the key for RHS
3. a `Func<MyTran,YourTran,TResult>` function for selecting the result

So from there you could use reflection to make this all a bit dynamic:

```
public static class DynamicJoinExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<dynamic> DynamicJoin(this IEnumerable<MyTran> myTran, IEnumerable<YourTran> yourTran, params Tuple<string, string>[] keys)
    {
        var outerKeySelector = CreateFunc<MyTran>(keys.Select(k => k.Item1).ToArray());
        var innerKeySelector = CreateFunc<YourTran>(keys.Select(k => k.Item2).ToArray());

        return myTran.Join(yourTran, outerKeySelector, innerKeySelector, (c, d) => new
        {
            MyId = c.Id,
            YourId = d.Id,
            MyAmtUSD = c.MyAmountUSD,
            MyAmtGBP = c.MyAmountGBP,
            YourAmtUSD = d.YourAmountUSD,
            YourAmtGBP = d.YourAmountGBP
        }, new ObjectArrayComparer());
    }

    private static Func<TObject, object[]> CreateFunc<TObject>(string[] keys)
    {
        var type = typeof(TObject);
        return delegate(TObject o)
        {
            var data = new object[keys.Length];
            for(var i = 0;i<keys.Length;i++)
            {
                var key = type.GetProperty(keys[i]);
                if(key == null)
                    throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid key: " + keys[i]);
                data[i] = key.GetValue(o);
            }
            return data;
        };
    }

    private class ObjectArrayComparer : IEqualityComparer<object[]>
    {

        public bool Equals(object[] x, object[] y)
        {
            return x.Length == y.Length
                   && Enumerable.SequenceEqual(x, y);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(object[] o)
        {
            var result = o.Aggregate((a, b) => a.GetHashCode() ^ b.GetHashCode());
            return result.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage to match your example would then be:

```
var query = fMyTranList.DynamicJoin(fYourTranList, 
               Tuple.Create("MyAmountGBP", "YourAmountGBP"));
```

but as the keys are `params` you can pass as many as you like:

```
var query = fMyTranList.DynamicJoin(fYourTranList, 
              Tuple.Create("MyAmountGBP", "YourAmountGBP"), 
              Tuple.Create("AnotherMyTranProperty", "AnotherYourTranProperty"));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/AAB2452

Comment: This assumes an anonymous object for the result - hence the `dynamic`. If you have a concrete class which represents the joined result just replace with that.

Comment: Thanks Jamiec. Which .Net Framework version you are using? I am using 4.0 and getting compile error. Code line - "data[i] = key.GetValue(o);" is causing issue. I get following error: Error No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: Jamiec, the code you provided works fine after making a small change in the line of code which was causing issue. This solves our one set of requirements. To make this code work for all our use cases, fMyTranList and fYourTranList will contain instances of ExpandoObject or similar dynamic type. In that scenario how can we join two collections of ExpandoObjects dynamically?